# Define multiple variables in a condition in ST

Tags: conditional-statements, st, codesys

I am currently programming/simulating a small plant in CODESYS. 
I have several outputs (that correspond to engines) that I need to test several times, so I want to create a condition that incorporates this test so I dont need to write the entire condition. 
For instance, i have the condition that verifies if

> A=TRUE AND B=TRUE AND C=TRUE AND D=TRUE

Can I create a condition like "verify engine" to use each time ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this (if I understood you correctly).

Here are two ways for example:

**1.** Create a variable that has the condition result and use the variable. You have to assign the variable at beginning, and then you can use the variable instead of that long code.

```
VAR
    EnginesOK   : BOOL;
END_VAR

//Check engines
EnginesOK := (A = TRUE AND B = TRUE AND C = TRUE AND D = TRUE); 

//.. Later ..

IF EnginesOK THEN
    //Do something
END_IF
```

**2.** Create a function, for example `F_VerifyEngines` that contains checks and returns the state as `BOOL`. Note: In this example A,B,C and D need to be global variables. You could also pass them as parameters for the function.

```
FUNCTION F_VerifyEngines : BOOL
VAR_INPUT
    //Add A,B,C,D here if needed
END_VAR
VAR
END_VAR

//Return the result
F_VerifyEngines := (A = TRUE AND B = TRUE AND C = TRUE AND D = TRUE);
```

Then you can use the function in code:

```
IF F_VerifyEngines() THEN
    //Do something
END_IF
```

The 2nd way is probably the one you were thinking.

By the way, there is no need to write `A = TRUE AND B = TRUE AND C = TRUE AND D = TRUE`, in my opinion, it's more clear to read when you use `A AND B AND C AND D` instead.